# Camel and MQTT Route

Tags: java, apache-camel, mqtt

I am working on a project and have decided to use Camel and ActiveMQ. I am attempting to create a route using Java and MQTT endpoints. Within this route I have also incorporated a Processor. This is what my route looks like:

```
from("mqtt:test?subscribeTopicName=zaq.avila.send")
            //.process(new RestProcessor())
            .to("mqtt:test?publishTopicName=zaq.avila.receive");
```

From my understanding, the route is consuming from zaq/avila/send, a processor is applied and then the message is published to zaq/avila/receive. The to() part does not appear to be happening, when I check the console, I see that the processor executes though no message is published to zaq/avila/receive. Also, within the web console I see that the messages in zaq/avila/send for enqueued and dequeued increment even when I only pusblished one message.  In addition, if I shutdown ActiveMQ I get the following:

```
 INFO | Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete,
 timeout in 7 seconds.
```

Also:

```
  WARN | Error occurred while shutting down service: Endpoint[mqtt://test?publish
 TopicName=zaq.avila.receive]. This exception will be ignored.
 java.lang.NullPointerException
```

These exception make me wonder that the exchange is not completing and something is missing. I need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not necessarily be the best answer, however, it works.

```
from("mqtt:test?subscribeTopicName=zaq.avila.send")
        .process(new RestProcessor())
        .to("jms:topic:zaq.avila.receive");
```

According to [ActiveMQ Doc](http://activemq.apache.org/mqtt.html)

> MQTT messages are transformed into an JMS ByteMessage. Conversely, the body of any JMS Message is converted to a byte buffer to be the payload of an MQTT message.

I was able to publish an mqtt message to a topic, apply a processor and receive the modified message as an mqtt message even though the specified endpoint is JMS.

If anyone can think of any possible downfalls I would gladly appreciate hearing from you. In my opinion, this removes the need to publish messages as MQTT.

Comment: This works ok mqtt publish to-> jms topic to-> mqtt subscribe.

But with the disadvantage that you loose the mqtt capabilities like retained messages & qos.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into [Camel MQTT component documentation](http://camel.apache.org/mqtt.html). There is note that this component can be only used for consuming messages if I understand it correctly.

```
Note: The component currently only supports polling (consuming) feeds.
```

It's quite weird. I'll investigate further.

Comment: Wow. That is weird, I don't know how I missed that. It doesn't explain why the doc would include the option publishTopicName if it doesn't support publishing messages.